# RayTracing, refraction code produces weird results

Tags: c++, 3d, physics, raytracing, lighting

This is the relevant code for refraction. I'm getting weird results when I change the index of refraction. Ideally, the sphere is supposed to show the distorted purple sphere and background due to refraction but instead it appears to look really like there's a red sphere inside the transparent one.

[image]

```
if(depth < MaxRecursion) {
    if(shape[pos]->transparent() == 1) {
        vec normal = N;
        // etam = index or refrac of medium, etao = index of outside;
        float eta, etao = 1.0, etam = 1.1
        float cosi = dot(N, unit_vector(r.dir());
        if(cosi < 0.0) {
            cosi = -cosi;
        }
        else {
            normal = -normal;
            swap(etao, etam);
        }
        eta = etao/etam;
        float c2 = 1.0 - eta*eta*(1.0 - cosi * cosi);
        if(c2 > 0.0) {
            vec dir = unit_vector(eta*unit_vector(r.dir()) - (eta*cosi -
                                  sqrtf(c2))*normal);
            ray refraction(r.p_at_par(t_near) + normal*1e-4, dir);
            total += color(refraction, shape, lighting, depth + 1);
            // color function is the current function
        }
        else { // total internal reflection
            ray reflect = reflection(unit_vector(r.dir()), normal, r.p_at_par(t_near));
            total += color(reflect, shape, lighting, depth + 1);
        }
    }
}
```

and for higher indexes of refraction, I get a completely white sphere (`etam = 1.9`)
I know than the error lies in this part of the code alone, because everything else works fine without the refraction code (i.e reflection, shadow, etc.)

[image]

Comment: it's not clear how you know that this image is not correct. And what happens when you try something simpler, like refraction through a plate, with displacement of a simple black line on a white background?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, but the plane properly refracts the background, it's only the sphere.